# Calling a external API class on Observer best practice

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

what are the good practice in magento on what im trying to do, basically i have a Class that sends some information to a external API, in my case is a invoice management system, so always that a order status is changed to complete i need to create a invoice on a external software. In my class i already have all the logic, but i not sure what is that best practice on magento of how i should do it.

For example is it OK using this example above on the Observer class.

```
include 'ApiName.class.php'; 

class Company_InvoiceSystemName_Model_Observer{

    public function createInvoice($observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $stateComplete = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE;
        if($order->getState() == $stateComplete && $order->getOrigData('state') != $stateComplete) {
            //Call Class API Methods for creating Invoice
            ...

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is common practice.

according to your method code it could observe `sales_order_save_after` event.